# Using passport-google-oauth with react-native

Tags: node.js, oauth, npm, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to use [passport-google-oauth](https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-google-oauth) in my react-native application. When I run the app it throws the error: `requiring unknown module util` . I've installed the package using `npm install ..` and I've also tried `npm install ... --save`

#### App/Components/Login.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth').OAuthStrategy;
...
```

#### package.json

```
{
  "name": "NativeApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node_modules/react-native/packager/packager.sh"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "passport": ">= 0.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native": "^0.4.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {}
}
```

#### index.ios.js

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var Login = require('./App/Components/login');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  NavigatorIOS,
} = React;

class AppStoreIOS extends React.Component{
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigatorIOS
        titleTextColor = '#0073A0'
        // barTintColor = '#183E63'
        initialRoute={{
          component: Login,
          title: 'AppStore v2.0',
          passProps: { myProp: 'foo' },
        }}
      />
    );
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't think this going to work for you. Passport expects to be run in an node.js (express based) environment, and will at least require some work to port it to using a webview for the Oauth flow, realistically it will be a lot of work.

Have a look at https://medium.com/@jtremback/oauth-2-with-react-native-c3c7c64cbb6d for an example of how to support oauth in react-native. I haven't tried this, but it looks pretty straight forward.